# How to reference a website article of discussion between two people, posted by a third?

Tags: citations

I would like to reference a website article at [Point-Counterpoint: Additive vs Subtractive Rapid Prototyping](http://www.rapidreadytech.com/2013/09/point-counterpoint-additive-vs-subtractive-rapid-prototyping/) that is a discussion between two individuals and posted by a third. I'm using Harvard British Standard referencing and it's not clear how exactly I should approach this situation.

In my references section, do I need a single reference crediting the poster, a single reference crediting both individuals in the discussion or separate references crediting each individual in the discussion? At the moment, I'm using the first option but I don't feel that it's correct.

It may be that an answer to this is a matter of opinion, rather than going by hard and fast rules, but I'd be extremely grateful for any help or advice with this issue!

Answer (score 2):

I would include as much bibliographic information as possible, but as long as the reader can unambiguously find the article I think that would suffice, and to find the article you need the author.

In your bibliography:

> Gooch, J (2013) *Point-Counterpoint: Additive vs. Subtractive Rapid Prototyping.* Webpage: http://www.rapidreadytech.com/2013/09/point-counterpoint-additive-vs-subtractive-rapid-prototyping/ [URL accessed: April 2015].

In your text you could use something like:

> Grimm, in Gooch (2013), states...